# Group by and sum grouping

Tags: ios, core-data, group-by

I have an entity Transaction which among others have 2 variables called "ownedAccount" and "amount".

What i would like to do is do get all Transaction's group them by ownedAccount and get the sum of the amounts in each Group

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a `NSFetchRequest` and use the `setPropertiesToGroupBy` method.

To get the sum of an attribute you have to use a combination of `NSExpression` and `NSExpressionDescription`:

```
NSExpression *amountExpr = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amount"];
NSExpression *totalAmountExpr = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[amountExpr]];
NSExpressionDescription *totalAmountExprDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[totalAmountExprDesc setName:@"totalAmount"];
[totalAmountExprDesc setExpression: totalAmountExpr];
[totalAmountExprDesc setExpressionResultType:NSDoubleAttributeType];
```

Further information about `NSExpression`: [Apple Docs NSExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSExpressionDescription_Class/NSExpressionDescription.html)

---

When creating the `NSFetchRequest` you have to make sure to set the result to be `NSDictionaryResultType` and to add the `totalAmountExprDesc` to the properties to fetch. Note that you also add the attribute that you want to group by to the properties to fetch.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"YourEntityName"];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"ownedAccount", totalAmountExprDesc, ...]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"ownedAccount"]];
```

Further information about `NSFetchRequest`: [Apple Docs NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html)

With that you have the basic fetch request to use for your query.